# MySQL 1443: what does it mean?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do an update, in MySQL 5.0, of the form:

```
update mytable.myfield t
set f = 'blah'
where t.id in (select v.id from myview v where ...);
```

MySQL tells me:

```
ErrorNr. 1443
The definition of table 'v' prevents operation UPDATE on table 't'.
```

The MySQL docs list this error, but (as usual) don't say what it means.  Can anyone shed some light on this for me?  I only reference the view in the subquery, and I only reference the table in the main query, and I don't know why these would prevent the update.  The only thing I found with google is a bug in the MySQL bug db related to triggers, but (AFAIK) there are no triggers in my db.

Comment: Does "myview" reference "mytable" anywhere?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the view *myview* must be based on the table *mytable*, so that as it makes changes to *myfield*, it loses track of what's in the view and therefore makes for an illegal update.

I would recommend looking at the definition of myview, so that you can write your query without referencing it. Then you may be able to work it out.

Alternatively, dump the list of ids to a temporary table and use that for your subquery.

Rob

Comment: "dump the list of ids to a temporary table" -> that's what I ended up doing.  In (My)SQL, whenever I write a query that's logically correct, the RDBMS has handled creating temporaries as needed (EXPLAIN says so!), so it didn't occur to me that MySQL *could* ever say "I'm not going to do that because it would require me to create a temporary table" (though in much more confusing verbiage).  Thanks for the tip.