# MySQL error 1443 workaround

Tags: mysql, sql

I believe my question can be referred to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225496/mysql-1443-what-does-it-mean) with almost the same title, but the answer was unfortunately not clear enough for me and that question is 6 years old too, maybe there are already some changes made to MySQL.

I wanted to delete a row(s) from a table without even updating/inserting/deleting rows from the view tables, from what I know, mysql unfortunately prevents us from making changes to a table that is referencing to a view table. 
I **need** to reference to the table which brings me to option 2 and my  question:

How can I "**dump the list to a temporary table and use that for your subquery**." or **is there a workaround to make this code work**?

I am using MySQL version 5.6.12 and
the code I'm working on:

```
DELETE FROM student
   WHERE (SUBSTR(student.stud_no,1,4) = 1234)
       AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT vr.stud_no FROM viewroom vr WHERE
           vr.stud_no = student.stud_no)
       AND NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT vlnr.stud_no,vlnr.status FROM viewlateststudentnr 
           vlnr WHERE (student.stud_no = vlnr.stud_no) AND (vlnr.status = 'confirmed') )
```

And the error :

> 1443 - The definition of table 'vr' prevents operation DELETE on table 'student'.

Comment: "delete a row(s) from a table without even updating/inserting/deleting rows from the view tables" VIEWs are not tables, you cannot keep a record in a view while removing it from the underlying table.

Comment: @Uueerdo the rows I want to change are not used by the viewtables I'm referencing. e.g. I just want to remove students that are not in the viewtables. So my query wont change the view tables directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, your views must include the table you want to delete from.  This suggests outer joins:

```
DELETE s
   FROM student s LEFT JOIN
        viewroom vr
        ON vr.stud_no = s.stud_no LEFT JOIN
        viewlateststudentnr vlnr
        ON s.stud_no = vlnr.stud_no AND vlnr.status = 'confirmed'
   WHERE SUBSTR(s.stud_no, 1, 4) = 1234 AND
         vr.stud_no IS NULL AND vlnr.stud_no IS NULL;
```

Comment: If this is a valid question, may you add to the answer _why it works with JOINS but not with EXISTS?_ Because in the end, I am just referencing to the view tables.

Comment: @wsssixteen . . . That is a limitation in MySQL.  You cannot reference the table being deleted (or updated) in the statement.  Apparently, this is also true for views as well as directly in the query.

Comment: Ahh okay, forgive me for my ignorance