# Is it posible to delete a row from an underlying table of a view?

Tags: mysql

i have a database with 2 tables and 1 view. One of the tables is a lookup table and i am using the view to present the data in one single table.

```
CREATE TABLE places (
 place_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 place VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (place_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tasks (
 task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 task VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 place_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (task_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (place_id) REFERENCES places(place_id)
);
```

In order to reduce the size of the select querys, i've created a view that presents the information of both tables.

```
CREATE VIEW view_planning AS
 SELECT tasks.task_id, tasks.task, places.place
 FROM tasks
 LEFT JOIN places ON places.place_id = tasks.place_id;
```

If i want to eliminate a row from the tasks table i have to do something like:

```
DELETE FROM tasks WHERE 
 task_id = (SELECT task_id FROM tasks WHERE 
             task="some task" AND 
             place_id= (SELECT place_id FROM places WHERE place = "some place"));
```

I would like to use the view like this so the querys are shorter:

```
DELETE FROM tasks WHERE 
 task_id = (SELECT task_id FROM view_planning WHERE 
             task="some task" AND place= "some place");
```

However i get

> Error Code: 1443. The definition of the table "view_planning" prevents operation DELETE on table "tasks".

Is there any way around this error?

Thank you.

Comment: In general deleting from views is a terrible idea. see mysql reference for rules on updateable view. If your view violates any of these rules you will not be able to delete from the view directly. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: MySQL has lots of strange restrictions on how views can be used.

Comment: @HLGEM He's not trying to delete from the view, he's just using the view in the query that selects which rows to remove from a table the view uses.

Comment: One of the rules is: Reference to nonupdatable view in the FROM clause which I took to mean if the view is not updateable it can't be used in a delete. The error message supports that. However, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33133234/mysql-error-1443-workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` rather than a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE t FROM tasks AS t
JOIN view_planning AS vp ON t.task_id = vp.task_id
WHERE vp.task = "some_task" AND vp.place = "some_place";
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your answer. 

I am getting: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. What is "safe update mode"?

Comment: That's a MySQL Workbench issue, not a problem with the query.

Comment: [Mysql Safe Update Explained](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2011/10/mysql-safe-update/)